# Is there a way by which I can handle the report data in powerbi based on user's role in a react application?

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, row-level-security

Need to find a solution by which data in powerbi report is displayed absed on user's role in react app, RLS is handled in powerbi but is there any other way?

I tried implementing RLS(Row Level Security) in powerbi but couldn't find way to pass through react app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass RLS details in the Request body while generating Embed Token. The embedded report will filter data accordingly to RLS applied.

References:

[Embed Token - Reports GenerateTokenInGroup - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-in-group#generate-a-report-embed-token-using-an-effective-identity-example)

[Using standard cloud based row-level security with embedded content in Power BI embedded analytics - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls#generate-an-embed-token)

[Generate an embed token in Power BI embedded analytics - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/generate-embed-token#row-level-security)

Please go through the considerations and limitation and make sure whether your scenario fits here.